# How can I change boot order in HP BIOS from hard disk to USB?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, bios

I am currently using an HP laptop with Ubuntu Linux, but I would like to switch to Debian. I have created a bootable USB of Debian but am unaware of how to boot from it. I have tried changing the boot order in BIOS, but it just booted into Ubuntu like usual. How can I change the boot order from BIOS? Please let me know if there is an easier way to do this in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke boot menu and see if pen drive name shown in boot menu or some shows usb pen drive as secondary hdd Most of BIOS of HP laptops and desktops can be entered by pressing “F10” or “Esc”. At the same time, the boot menu can be accessed by “F9”. However, if it is an old HP computer, the key may be “Delete” which can enter the BIOS and boot menu.

If not work kindly tell me the HP model number is will find the option